# Where are OpenOffice templates stored?

Tags: openoffice, templates

My computer has somehow gotten out of sync. I can save a document as a template in a directory of my choosing, but when I go to use the Templates and Documents dialog, I get this:

[image: Templates and documents dialog]

I have no idea where on my hard drive these folders are. Where is "Templates/My Templates"?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Windows XP

```
C:\Documents and Settings\User_Name\Application Data\OpenOffice.org\3\user\template
```

Windows Vista & 7

```
C:\users\User_Name\AppData\OpenOffice.org\3\user\template
```

Linux

```
~/.openoffice.org/3/user/template
```

Comment: The crux of the matter is to realize that the path is invisible. You need to type the folder names in order to see their contents. In my case it's C:\Users\<user name>\AppData\Roaming\OpenOffice\4\user\template .

Answer (score 1):

You should find them at:

> ~/.openoffice.org/3/user/template

If you have OpenOffice 2, then replace 3 with 2 in the above path.

Answer (score 1):

This location can also be moved.  Navigate to Tools - Options - OpenOffice.org - Paths and change the value for "Templates".  There can be multiple template paths, or, you can delete the existing path and create a new one altogether.

Answer (score 1):

As of **March 2018, LibreOffice 5.1** the template folder for Linux is under:

```
~/.config/libreoffice/4/user/template/
```

Btw: searching for `.ott` (writer templates) helped me find it…

Answer (score 0):

C:\users\User_Name\AppData\Roaming\OpenOffice.org\3\user\template

Answer (score 0):

I'm running `Apache OpenOffice 4.1.15` where the template files are located in:

`C:\Users\x\AppData\Roaming\OpenOffice\4\user\template`

Running on: `Windows 11 (23H2, 22631.3007)`

Answer (score -1):

Windows:

`dir /s/b %APPDATA%\openoffice\*.ott`

Comment: Every version of Windows that’s ever been released?  Every version that will ever be released?   To make your answer more useful and more durable, please [edit] it to state the version(s) of Windows for which this is true.